# Where is the Rakefile in a Railsapp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

As the question states, where is the Rakefile in a Railsapp?

In my app it is no where to be found. I'm working on an app with another developer and he's just pushed code to the Rakefile as such:

```
7  Rakefile

@@ -0,0 +1,7 @@

+# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,

+# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

+

+require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

+require 'rake'

+

+Newapp::Application.load_tasks
```

Although, I can't find this code anywhere in the actual app. Please help clear this up for me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Conventionally, the Rakefile usually goes at the Rails root of your project (this is the location first generated when you ran `rails new ...`).

`rake` can also be run by using a Rakefile anywhere, by using `rake -f path/to/my/rakefile.rb`, so if you need to diverge from the convention for some reason, that's possible too.

However, note that many third-party services presume that it's possible to run `rake` from the root of your project and get the desired result (e.g. `heroku rake`).